# How to control theme application in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to apply theme to the `<ul>` tag while displaying the contacts details. But the data-theme and list-divider-theme gets applied to the `<ul>` contents only after the first time contact details are displayed. My code is as follows.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
$(function(){
       $(".contactSelect").live('click',function(){

           $('#contactdetail').empty();

           var txt = "<ul data-inset='true' list-divider-theme='b' id='contactdetail'></ul>";
        $("#box").append(txt);
        id = this.id;
        $('#contactdetail').append($('<li/>', {
                    'class':'contactdetailClass',
                    'data-role':'list-divider',   
                    'text':'Name'                               
                }));
        $('#contactdetail').append($('<li/>', {
                    'class':'contactdetailClass',
                    'text':mainContacts[id].displayName   
                }));
        $('#contactdetail').append($('<li/>', {
                    'class':'contactdetailClass',
                    'data-role':'list-divider',
                    'text':mainContacts[id].phoneNumbers[0].type                                   
                }));
        $('#contactdetail').append($('<li/>', {
                    'class':'contactdetailClass',
                    'text':mainContacts[id].phoneNumbers[0].value  
                }));
        $('contactdetail').trigger('create');

        $('#contactdetail').listview();
        $('#contactdetail').listview('refresh');
    });
});

    function onDeviceReady() {

                var options = new ContactFindOptions();
                options.multiple=true; 
                var fields = ["*"];
                navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
            }

            function onSuccess(contacts) {

                  mainContacts=contacts;
                    for (var i=0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                        $('#contactContainer').append($('<li/>', {   
                              }).append($('<a/>', {
                              'id':i,
                            'href': '#two',
                            'data-role':'button',
                            'text': contacts[i].displayName,
                            'class': 'contactSelect'
                        })));
                    };

                    $('ul').listview('refresh');
             }

            function onError(contactError) {

                    }
```

Please help me to find out why the theme is not applied to the `<ul>` for the first while displaying the contact details? The first time output is shown following snapshot:

Comment: `$('contactdetail').trigger('create');

        $('#contactdetail').listview();
        $('#contactdetail').listview('refresh');` why all that? `$('#contactdetail').listview();` is enough. What do you want to achieve? styling list-items (li) or dividers?

Comment: I have tried each one of it individually and combined.

Comment: @Omar I want to achieve styling the list-items. And I am able to achieve it. The problem is that when the User clicks on one of the Contact to view Contact Details for the first time, the styling is not achieved! :(

Comment: you mean that once list item is clicked, theme change?

Comment: Nope. The theme to the list items doesn't get applied when the user clicks on a particular contact. This happens only once. Later everything works fine.